# Django and Tox testing

Tags: python-3.x, django, testing, automated-tests, tox

I have a django package that I like to test against different versions of django using tox and with the `python manage.py test` command.
On the newer versions, django has

```py
from django.urls import reverse
```

available, but this doesnt exist on e.g. Django 1.8, because its in a diff path, but this version I am trying to test against, too.

Can someone point me to resources to find out how I can still make the tox testing pass?
Whats the correct way of testing this? Is there some sort of conditional import I can do based on django version?
Or maybe sth like

```
try:
    from django.urls import reverse
except ImportError:
    from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
```

Im just not sure if this is the standard and safest way :)

Thanks!

tox config

```
[tox]
envlist =
    {py27,py35}-django18,
    {py27,py35}-django19,
    {py27,py35}-django110,
    {py27,py35,py36,py37}-django111,
    {py35,py36,py37}-django20,
    {py35,py36,py37}-django21,
    {py35,py36,py37}-django22,
    {py35,py36,py37,py38}-django30,
    {py38,py39,py310}-django40,

[testenv]
commands =
    python manage.py test

deps =
    django18: django==1.8.*
    django19: django==1.9.*
    django110: django==1.10.*
    django111: django==1.11.*
    django20: django==2.0.*
    django21: django==2.1.*
    django22: django==2.2.*
    django30: django>=3.0a1,<3.1
    django40: django==4.0.*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is nothing which `tox` has to take care of, as `tox` is just driving the test runner, in your your case `python manage.py test`.

You need to update your code and/or your tests to pass a `python manage.py test` for Django 1.8.